# Bitwise cast from __m128 to __m128i on MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, sse

On Linux and Mac, one can do

```
__m128 x;
__m128i n = (__m128i)x;
```

This operation copies the bit representation of x to n, and is useful for implementing various branch-free conditional operations operating on SSE floating point registers.  On MSVC 11, it gives

```
eikonal-generated.h(1228) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from '__m128' to '__m128i'; No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

What is the equivalent in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Note that I am not asking for the standard float-to-int conversion function _mm_cvtepi32_ps, which does numerically meaningful conversion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With MSVC you need to use:

[_mm_castsi128_ps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514029%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for bitwise cast from `__m128i` to `__m128`

and

[_mm_castps_si128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514099%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for bitwise cast from `__m128` to `__m128i`

For other compilers (gcc, ICC, *et al*) you can just use normal casts.

Comment: You can actually get away without any casts at all if you use `-flax-vector-conversions` (gcc, icc)

Comment: Now the question would be if one *can* or *must* use normal casts on other compilers, i.e. do these cast intrisics exist in *gcc*, *icc* and all the others, too, and thus provide a platform-independent solution (which is one of the major points of intrinsics at all)? I for myself just always went the ugly way of a `reinterpret_cast` (or its C pointer cast version), which the compiler of course also made into a noop, yet it doesn't look too good and an intrinsic would be a clearer option.

Comment: @Christian: unfortunately there are various minor discrepancies between MS and the civilized world when it comes to SSE intrinsics etc - I have a common header that I use for portable SSE code where I implement wrappers and various macros which get conditionally compiled for the different platforms.

Comment: @PaulR So those casts are not supported on *gcc*, *icc*, ...?

Comment: @Christian: I believe they are supported by ICC, but not by gcc et al. Also they didn't exist in early version of MSVC (prior to 2008) so had to be implemented using unions.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I'm late to the party, but these are supported since GCC 4 (according to the [bug tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19418); I have verified it in 4.9).

Comment: @EmilStyrke: thanks for that update - useful to know for future reference.